# ABM_GETTASKBARPOS window handle

Tags: shell, winapi

The documentation of `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS` says:

```
You must specify the cbSize and hWnd when sending this message
```

But what should I set the `hWnd` member of the structure to? I googled a bit and saw that some people do the following:

```
abd.hWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
```

But this is really ugly code if you ask me because it relies on system internals, i.e. assuming that the task bar's window name is `Shell_TrayWnd`.

I did some experiments and at least on Windows 7, `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS` works fine without passing a window handle in the `hWnd` structure member so I'm wondering whether this is a documentation error on MSDN after all. The documentation really doesn't make sense to me. Why would Windows want me to pass the window handle of the task bar at all? This is something internal that `SHAppBarMessage()` should know itself.

Can anybody shed some light onto this? What should I set `hWnd` to? Or is this maybe a documentation error on MSDN? As I said, it works just fine when `hWnd` is just set to `NULL`.

Comment: This was asked recently. You don't need to pass a window handle.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050506-32/?p=35693  Hehe.

Comment: `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS` has been around since the Taskbar was first introduced in Windows 95, and has always allowed the `hWnd` field to be NULL in that message (see the `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS` example in [Extend the Windows 95 Shell with Application Desktop Toolbars](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S274.aspx), which clearly states that `hWnd` is ignored).  So I don't know why the documentation has ever stated that `hWnd` must be specified when that is clearly not the case.

Comment: The documentation also says that it needs at least XP so it looks like a newer API...

Comment: @Andreas: That is not surprising, considering that whenever Microsoft drops support for a Windows version, they usually remove that version from the *Minimum Supported* references in most MSDN documentation.  When Microsoft recently dropped support for XP, the documentation for most APIs that actually exist on XP were updated to now say Vista instead.  It is very annoying that Microsoft does this, it causes problems when people need to write new code that still targets older Windows versions.

Comment: Hmm, that's really annoying then. I was even thinking about alternatives to `SHAppBarMessage()` because the fact that it was said to require XP scared me off because I'm targetting older versions as well. If they really do this, it's pretty ugly. Somebody should get Raymond Chen to convince Microsoft to adhere to proper documentation standards again.

Comment: The documentation about behavior specific to Windows XP also gets deleted, so the documentation describes how the function works in Windows Vista and higher. (If this weren't done, documentation would get clogged up with discussion of things like "Well on Windows NT 3.51, the function had this behavior, but that changed in Windows 2000 and higher.") But yeah, it bugs me too.

Comment: And then you have things like the docs for `LVHITTESTINFO`, which as well as saying "This structure supersedes the `LVHITTESTINFO` structure", also contains a table where half of the field descriptions start with "Windows Vista:" and half don't. MSDN is a mess.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Indeed, that sentence at the top looks like a doc bug. It boggles the mind how an identically named structure could supersede a previous one. But the stuff "Windows Vista" is not a bug, or even especially annoying. Everything with the "Windows Vista" label is only supported on Windows Vista and later. The half that don't say "Windows Vista" are available and supported on older versions, too. That's helpful information. I guess you're saying they should delete it since the "Minimum Supported Version" was auto-updated to Vista? I'd rather they didn't...

Comment: Good thing I still have old MSDN docs on CD-ROM. I can use these for reference to see when certain APIs were really introduced because the online MSDN reference seems everything but reliable here.

Comment: It is a difference in the interpretation of the word "supported". You are interpreting it in a *technical* sense (*i.e.*, supported by the operating system). But MSDN means it in a non-technical sense. Operating systems before Windows Vista are not supported, so none of their APIs are supported, either. If you call tech support, you won't get very far with a Windows XP question. Yes, looking at an old version of MSDN is very necessary if you need to support older OS versions. Me too.